# NodeJS Clustering

Tags: node.js

I have a nodejs app that has one getUsers endpoint, this endpoint gets the first 10 users from a mongodb database and returns them in a JSON response.

Lets say this is a sync process (async wont make any sense here since i need to fetch and return the result in the same request) and the entire process takes 1 sec. So, if I have 4 CPU in a virtual machine and I am running the nodejs in cluster mode (meaning 4 nodejs processes running together).

Q1) Does this mean my app can handle 4 simultaneous request per second? If this is true, how can my app handle 1000 request per second?

Q2) I know nodejs is single threaded but Is there anyway the nodejs instance can use more than 1 thread per CPU so that it can handle more request per cpu per second?

Answer (score 1):

> Q1) Does this mean my app can handle 4 simultaneous request per second?

If we **neglect** load balancer process time, your cluster could handle around 4 RPS (requests per second).

> If this is true, how can my app handle 1000 request per second?

In short, by scaling via **threads** or **server instances**.
More details will be described below.

> Q2) I know nodejs is single threaded

Falsy statement.
**Node.JS** has at least **4 threads** to handle **I/O operations** and few more threads for other under the hood processes.
This makes even **single** Node.JS instance pretty powerful to handle **many** async  operations.

> but Is there anyway the nodejs instance can use more than 1 thread per CPU

Yes, you can use [worker_thread](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html) to create **as many threads as you wish**.

> so that it can handle more request per cpu per second?

Firstly, you have to make your **request handler** works **asynchronous** so it can  process more than one request at a time within single thread (using single CPU core).
Then you would like to scale it up via **worker_threads** to use more threads i.e. more cores to process higher amount of requests.
And that's all inside single process.

P.S. Since each new thread will use **new core**, there exists a recommendation to spawn around `N - 1` threads where `N` is number of logical cores on your CPU.

Answer (score 0):

> Q1) Does this mean my app can handle 4 simultaneous request per second? If this is true, how can my app handle 1000 request per second?

Yes, not because of multiple instances but because Nodejs handles each incoming request asynchronously, even though the processing of a request is itself synchronous. You can handle the 4 of them with a single instance.

The number of requests that can be handled depends on your server.

I recommend doing a performance test. For example, I have recently used [Grafana K6](https://k6.io/)

> Q2) I know nodejs is single threaded but Is there anyway the nodejs instance can use more than 1 thread per CPU so that it can handle more request per cpu per second?

No, if you want use more CPU you have to create multiple instances in cluster mode.

- [Check this out](https://blog.devgenius.io/how-to-scale-a-nodejs-application-a51d3e8e2d36)